# Resharper Tip/Trick... is this possible?

Tags: c#, resharper, code-cleanup

How can I have Resharper convert code file like

```
using Stuff;
using Stuff.MoreStuff;
using Stuff.MoreStuff.EvenMoreStuff;

namespace CoolStuff 
{
// src code
}
```

To

```
namespace CoolStuff 
{
  #region Using Statements
  using Stuff;
  using Stuff.MoreStuff;
  using Stuff.MoreStuff.EvenMoreStuff;
  #endregion

// src code
}
```

I just like it this way, it "I think" is in one of the stylecop rules too. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks

Comment: Moving the `using` directives to be within the namespace is a StyleCop rule, surrounding with a region is not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your ReSharper Options, find the Namespace Imports page under C#->Formatting Style.  In there, check the "Add using directive to the deepest scope" check box.

Then, go down to the bottom Tools section, and select the Code Cleanup page.  Create a new cleanup profile, and check the "Embrace 'using' directives in region" option, supplying "Using Statements" as the region name on the next line.  Make sure that "Optimize 'using' directives" is checked.  You can turn the other cleanup settings on or off as you like.

Then, you can run code cleanup on a file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd> if you've set that profile as your silent clean-up profile).